# virtualboxでmacアドレスを変更するとは

Tags: linux, virtualbox

現在VirtualBoxでlinuxを動かして勉強をしている学生です。
macアドレスについて質問させてください。

macアドレスは製造時に付加される固有のアドレスという認識です。
そしてmacアドレスは可変であることを知りました。で、仮想環境のLinuxのターミナルにおいてMACアドレスを変えればホストのMACアドレスごと書き変わるのでしょうか？
それとも僕の認識がどこかおかしいのでしょうか？

また、MACアドレスを変更すると再度戻した方がいいのでしょうか？
具体例含め教えていただければ助かります。よろしくおねがします

Comment: 「MACアドレスの変更」とは具体的にどんな手順で行っていますか？Kali Linuxはあまり詳しくありませんが、ディストリビューションの用途を考えると単に偽装しているだけの場合もあります。 / 何かしらの手順で書き換えた場合も、仮想マシンの生成時に割り当てられたMACアドレスと、変更したMACアドレスとが一致しないことで問題が出る可能性もあるので、可能なら元に戻した方がいいでしょう。 / ただし仮想環境なら事前にスナップショットを取っておいて復元するのが一番簡単な気もします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

仮想環境のMACアドレスとホストのMACアドレスは別のモノとなります。
仮想環境のNWインターフェースは仮想のインターフェースとなります。

また「MACアドレスを変更→戻す」についてですが、利用用途を記載するとJorns様の期待する返答が返ってきやすいと思います。私が思いつくのは、NWインターフェースの取り換えが発生した場合に、元のMACアドレスを利用したいなどと言った場合に変更が発生するかと思います。

Comment: 利用用途はkaliを用いたセキュリティの勉強です。当方、完全独学のため知識が不十分なせいかこの返答で十分なのかわかりません。加えて仮想インターフェースが理解できません、結論としては戻すことが安パイなのでしょうか？

Comment: セキュリティについてあまり詳しくないのでお応えできる範囲で回答します。MACアドレス指定で攻撃を受けた際に自端末のMACアドレスを変更して攻撃をかわすということになりますでしょうか？最終的にはMACアドレスを元に戻すのが良いかと思います。但し、気を付けなければいけないのは一時的に変更したMACアドレスがNW上に存在しないかということです。存在した場合は正常な通信ができなくなります。また、セキュリティ対策として、一般的な方法の一つとしては決められた端末、またはポートのみ通信を許可するというのがあります。あと仮想インターフェースと表現しましたのは、実際にインターフェースがあるのではなくお使いのVirtualBox上に仮想のインターフェースが作成されているということです。以上でよかったでしょうか。あまり詳しくないため回答に不足がありましたら申し訳ないです。

Comment: なんとなくですがわかりました、ひとまず、アドレスの被りにだけ注意して戻そうと思います、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox(に限った話ではないですが)の仮想マシンは、それぞれ自分の仮想NICを持っていて、MACアドレスもその仮想NICごとに異なるものが割り当てられます。(当然ホストとも別のものです)

仮想マシンから見えているのは仮想NICなので、変更もこの仮想NICに対するものになります。仮想マシンからホストの環境を変更することはできませんしできたら困ります。

変更後戻した方がよいかは環境次第です。自宅など自分が管理している環境なら放っておいてもいいのではないでしょうか。どうせ再起動すれば元に戻ります。

Comment: なるほど！再起動でも戻るんですね！ちなみにwifiadapterのMACアドレスを仮想マシンで変更しても戻りますか？